# MyPy gives no warning on clear type error, am I holding it wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I am learning how to use MyPy. I thought the following code should raise warnings because it might return `True` which is not an `int` as annotated. But MyPy is silent about it when ran with `mypy program.py`.

```
import typing

def is_prime(n: int) -> int:

    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return n

    return True
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `print(isinstance(True, int))`

Answer (score 0):

> A Boolean type was added to Python 2.3. Two new constants were added
>   to the **builtin** module, True and False. (True and False constants
>   were added to the built-ins in Python 2.2.1, but the 2.2.1 versions
>   are simply set to integer values of 1 and 0 and aren't a different
>   type.)

`bool` is a subclass of `int` with two singleton values, `True` and `False`, that are equal to `1` and `0` respectively. Python does this conversion internally.
See the below samples:

```
print(True + 1)      # outputs 2
print(True - 1)      # outputs 0
print(True - 2)      # outputs -1
a = True
print(a)             # outputs True because no mathematical calculation
print(True + True + 1) # Outputs 3
print(False + 1)     #  Outputs 3
print(False + True)     #  Outputs 1
```

Refer:

- https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-bool.html
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/

Comment: It's not an implicit conversion, bool is simply as subclass of `int` with two singleton values, `True` and `False`, that are equal to `1` and `2`

Comment: Yeah, I meant same. Thanks for the edits. There is a minor typo in your comment, should be 1 and 0. :-)