# Mypy type checker doesn't work correctly for a list of integers and booleans

Tags: python, boolean, mypy

```
from typing import List

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a: int = 3
    b: List[int] = [1, 2, True]
    c: List[str] = ["1", "2", 35.5]
    a = False
```

It only gives me a warning for the `c` list, so if I commented this out it claims "Success: no issues found in 1 source file". But it's clearly wrong, isn't it?

What editor, plugin or whatever should I use for static type checking in Python?

Here is some proof:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `True` and `False` are identical to the integers `1` and `0`.

Therefore Mypy cannot distinguish `[1, 2, True]` from `[1, 2, 1]` and `a = False` from `a = 0`.

See also:

- [MyPy gives no warning on clear type error, am I holding it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815018/mypy-gives-no-warning-on-clear-type-error-am-i-holding-it-wrong)
- [Is False == 0 and True == 1 an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the)